# Asigning a missing value to particular value in a DataFrames

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

Hi I have a dataframe where I want to replace a particular value such as `99` with a `missing` value. Its difficult to do this as you cannot change the column value types. One way to do this would be

```
df = DataFrame(
    :x1 => [1,2,99],
    :x2 => [10,99,11],
    :x3 => [20,21,22]
)

ammended_cols = replace.(eachcol(df), 99 => missing) 
df_n = map((x,y) -> x => y, names(df),ammended_cols) |> DataFrame

julia> @show df_n
df_n = 3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2       x3
     │ Int64?   Int64?   Int64?
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │       1       10      20
   2 │       2  missing      21
   3 │ missing       11      22
```

However I am wondering if there is easier/better way to do this such as using `replace!` to mutate the existing dataframe. However doing this would result in a type conversion error

```
replace!.(eachcol(df), 1.23 => missing)

ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Missing to an object of type Int64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U can use the `allowmissing` function ([official docs](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Missings.allowmissing)) which changes the type of each column in the `DataFrame` to allow missing values i.e. the type of each column will change from `T` to `Union{T, Missing}`, where `T` is the original type of the column, and `Union{T, Missing}` means that it could have either the `T` type or the special `missing` type.

```
df = DataFrame(
    :x1 => [1,2,99],
    :x2 => [10,99,11],
    :x3 => [20,21,22]
)

# Converting df to allow missing data
allowmissing!(df)

replace!.(eachcol(df), 99 => missing)
```

The exclamation mark `!` in `allowmissing!(df)` means that it directly changes the `df`, instead of creating a new `DataFrame`. If you want to create a new `DataFrame`, the code could be:

```
df = DataFrame(
    :x1 => [1,2,99],
    :x2 => [10,99,11],
    :x3 => [20,21,22]
)

df_n = allowmissing(df)

df_n = DataFrame(replace.(eachcol(df_n), 99 => missing), names(df_n))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep this works :). The last line `df_n = replace.(eachcol(df_new), 99 => missing) |> DataFrame`doesnt work thought. Dont think you can convert it to a DataFrame this way cause replace produces just a vector and hence the name columns are missing

Comment: @imantha I have updated the answer for u - Apparently you have to specify column names when creating a `DataFrame` from a vector of vectors - the 1st parameter that goes into `DataFrame()` is the data, the 2nd parameter are column names - i.e. the last line should be `df_n = DataFrame(replace.(eachcol(df_n), 99 => missing), names(df_n))`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, to create a new data frame you can write:

```
julia> ifelse.(df .== 99, missing, df)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2       x3
     │ Int64?   Int64?   Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │       1       10     20
   2 │       2  missing     21
   3 │ missing       11     22
```

and to update an existing in-place:

```
julia> df[!, :] .= ifelse.(df .== 99, missing, df)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1       x2       x3
     │ Int64?   Int64?   Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │       1       10     20
   2 │       2  missing     21
   3 │ missing       11     22
```